# Google Chrome does not show all results if I type a searchword into the address bar

Tags: google-chrome, history, google-chrome-extensions

It's been two months since I've been using Chrome and now I found the first thing that really annoys me:
If type a word into the address bar I would except to make a search in the history for that particular word. Unfortunately, the search results usually don't include the page I was looking for.

For example, yesterday I've seen a clip on YouTube. Today I want to watch it again, and type the song name in the address bar. Google won't show me the link to the movie.
I literally need to type "youtube SONGNAME" instead of "SONGNAME".

Another example is that in some of my domains, I've an image directory, like this:
www.mydomain.com/images/house.jpg
www.mydomain.com/images/car.jpg

I'd except Chrome to suggest both Urls, but Google won't if I type in "www.mydomain.com/images". What the heck?

Is there some plugin that uses the input from the address bar, searches for the input in the history (meaning in the page title and the Url) and displays all results in the DropDownBox? That is the only feature I'm missing from firefox.

Comment: Version?​​​​​​​

Comment: @Synetechinc.: 10.0.648.204

Comment: I wonder if it doesn't show results that are synched from another device. For example, I visited a website on my phone today, and that shows up on my desktop's history page but not when I search for it in the address bar—but it does show an older article I visited on the very same website when I search for that. And my desktop's address-bar results started including the article I visited on my phone once I visited it on my desktop as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The address bar shows a mix of web results, see the little globe icon next to them, yes. For history its best ot hit <kbd>Ctrl-H</kbd> and search from there. Also see the Search section under the Basic Options page.

Answer (score 5):

Go to settings>advanced settings> privacy

then uncheck the option

> Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in
>   the address bar or the app launcher search box

Comment: I did not expect this to work, but it did. Apparently the suggestions from the prediction service will have higher priority than elements from the history when they are enabled. Disabling it allows history elements to make it onto the list.

Comment: yes and you can use a search box separately :)

Comment: This should be the answer compared the "Google staff" answer by invert!!! I really was frustrated with this.. URLs that I visit everyday did not appear and I did not want to do CTRL+H - thanks for this!

Comment: In later versions of Chrome this is no longer an option.